# How do I wrap a box-shadow around a cluster of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a bunch of pill-like items that have flexed elements inside.  I'd like to wrap the entire "pill" in a box-shadow, but I'm fighting the `block`y div that defines the flex.

I've tried playing with `inline-flex` inside individual `div`s, but that broke the uniformity of each "pill" having the same width for each section.

In the code below, I have two examples of what I've tried with the box shadow: attaching it to the flex container and attaching it to the individual flex items.

https://codepen.io/rewing/pen/oNdZNxb

HTML and CSS

```css
.box-shadow-test-1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box-shadow-test-2>div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.thing {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: default;
}
.thing > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
.thing .indicator {
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
}
.thing .left-indicator {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  flex-basis: 13px;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-1 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-2 {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-3 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-4 {
  background-color: #ff8989;
}
.thing .name {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-basis: 195px;
}
.thing .change {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-basis: 135px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}
.thing .right-indicator {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-1 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-1:hover {
  background-color: #A6D9AD;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-2 {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-3 {
  background-color: #fcf95c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-3:hover {
  background-color: #E3E043;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-4 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="things">
   <div class="cluster">
      <div class="thing box-shadow-test-1">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-2">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 1</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-2">state-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="thing thing-2 box-shadow-test-2">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-2">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 2</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-2">state-2</div>
      </div>
     <div class="thing thing-3">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-3">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 3</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-3">state-3 longer</div>
      </div>
     <div class="thing thing-4">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-4">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 4</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-4">state-4 short</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

For clarification, the third box shadow'd pill in this list is what I'm trying to create.  The first attempt is wrapped around the `block`y div, the second attempt shows the box-shadow inside the pill itself, but the third (photoshopped) pill has the box-shadow only around the outside of the flex container.

[image]

Comment: The requirement seems to be a little unclear. can you rewrite that or post the image of the requirement?

Comment: @Nitheesh Absolutely, added the image in an edit.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
:root {
 --shadowColor: hsl(0deg 20% 20% / 0.7);
}

.thing {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: default;
}

.thing>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

.thing .indicator {
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
}

.thing .left-indicator {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  flex-basis: 13px;
}

.thing .left-indicator.state-3 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
}

.thing .name {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-basis: 195px;
}

.thing .change {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-basis: 135px;
}

.thing .right-indicator {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.thing .right-indicator.state-3 {
  background-color: #fcf95c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thing .right-indicator.state-3:hover {
  background-color: #E3E043;
}

.withShadow {
  /* using the 'filter' property to apply a drop-shadow, using the
     drop-shadow() function:
      (first) 0:          the x-offset (positive numbers moves to the right,
                          negative to the left),
      (second) 0:         the y-offset (positive numbers move down, negative
                          numbers go up),
      0.5em:              the spread of the colour,
      var(--shadowColor): the colour of the shadow (here using a CSS property)
     */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em var(--shadowColor));
}
```

```html
<!-- for brevity I removed all but the one element you said you wanted to have the shadow
     (and, similarly, removed the unnecessary CSS for the removed elements): -->
<div class="things">
    <!-- I added a single class-name 'withShadow' to apply the CSS (because I was unsure of
         the situations in which you wanted the shadow added; obviously you can add the
         CSS declarations to another class if it makes more sense: -->
    <div class="thing thing-3 withShadow">
      <div class="indicator left-indicator state-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="name">Name 3</div>
      <div class="change">Property 1</div>
      <div class="indicator right-indicator state-3">state-3 longer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/erkbx5ya/).

References:

- [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)
- [`drop-shadow()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/drop-shadow).
- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Comment: Oh wow, a drop-shadow filter.  I didn't even know that was a thing.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to have introduced you to something new! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 75%)); in the .thing-3 class

```css
.box-shadow-test-1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box-shadow-test-2>div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.thing {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: default;
}

.thing-3 {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 75%));
}

.thing > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
.thing .indicator {
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
}
.thing .left-indicator {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  flex-basis: 13px;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-1 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-2 {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-3 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
}
.thing .left-indicator.state-4 {
  background-color: #ff8989;
}
.thing .name {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-basis: 195px;
}
.thing .change {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-basis: 135px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}
.thing .right-indicator {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-1 {
  background-color: #bff2c6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-1:hover {
  background-color: #A6D9AD;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-2 {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-3 {
  background-color: #fcf95c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-3:hover {
  background-color: #E3E043;
}
.thing .right-indicator.state-4 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="things">
   <div class="cluster">
      <div class="thing box-shadow-test-1">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-2">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 1</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-2">state-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="thing thing-2 box-shadow-test-2">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-2">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 2</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-2">state-2</div>
      </div>
     <div class="thing thing-3">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-3">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 3</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-3">state-3 longer</div>
      </div>
     <div class="thing thing-4">
         <div class="indicator left-indicator state-4">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="name">Name 4</div>
         <div class="change">Property 1</div>
         <div class="indicator right-indicator state-4">state-4 short</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This absolutely works.  Thanks a lot!